# Cant install Java on Wand Board Quad running Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, java, minecraft

I picked up the Wand Board and was curios to see on how well it can perform as a Minecraft Server. So i downloaded the JDK 8 from the official site for ARM and extracted it to my OPT folder, after doing so i ran "java -version" from the folder and it said java is not found.

```
inaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:~$ opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -Xmx768M -Xms768M ${GC_OPTS} -jar Tekkit.jar nogui
-bash: opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: No such file or directory
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:~$
```

Even though it exists!'

```
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:~$ cd /opt
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt$ ls
jdk1.8.0
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt$ cd jdk1.8.0
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/jdk1.8.0$ ls
COPYRIGHT  README.html                  bin  include  lib  release
LICENSE    THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt  db   jre      man  src.zip
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/jdk1.8.0$ cd bin
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin$ ls
appletviewer  javac     jdeps       jsadebugd     pack200      servertool
extcheck      javadoc   jhat        jstack        policytool   tnameserv
idlj          javah     jinfo       jstat         rmic         unpack200
jar           javap     jjs         jstatd        rmid         wsgen
jarsigner     jcmd      jmap        keytool       rmiregistry  wsimport
java          jconsole  jps         native2ascii  schemagen    xjc
java-rmi.cgi  jdb       jrunscript  orbd          serialver
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin$
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please add `ls -l /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin`?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do an `apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`? Or do you specifically need a 1.8 version?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle JDK 8 release for ARM is built for hard floating point ABI. Is Ubuntu for Wandboard a soft-float or hard-float build? If it is soft float you will get the error you reported above. Try a JDK that is built for the soft float ABI (probably JDK 7 as I don't think Oracle has released a soft-float JDK 8 to date).

Answer (score 0):

Forts, try with:

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
```

As I can see, you forgot to put a slash in the front of the command and thi is for sure a problem.

Second, check in Nautilus what exactly is the name of the file. It must to be exactly 'java' and after I saw your comments I suspect that the name of the file contain one or more spaces at the end or maybe other strange character. So try to rename in Nautilus and you will see.

Also I suggest you to add `/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/` directory to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/
```

See also: [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/147044)

Comment: No dice, it says 
-bash: /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: No such file or directory
linaro@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin$

Comment: @user185257 So, you are in `/opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/` dyrectory, you run `java` and you get that error? ...impossible

Comment: yep, its very strange, i dont know what to do, im considering to wipe my system.

Comment: @user185257 and did you tried to change the PATH and then to run  java?

Comment: Yes i did. Still no dice.

Comment: @user185257 See my new edits

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

The problem was that Java was referencing `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` which does not exist on the system. When you look at `/lib` the only loader file is `/lib/ld-linux.so.3` so just soft link them and it works. Below is how I worked it out and what I did to fix it.

Enjoy

```
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# java
-su: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# strings java

/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
qwwBI
libpthread.so.0
_Jv_RegisterClasses
libjli.so
_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
JLI_Launch
__gmon_start__
_ITM_registerTMCloneTable
libdl.so.2
libc.so.6
abort
__libc_start_main
lib.so
$ORIGIN/../lib/arm/jli:$ORIGIN/../lib/arm
SUNWprivate_1.1
GLIBC_2.4
1.8.0_06-b23
java

root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# ls /lib/ld*
/lib/ld-linux.so.3
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# ln -s /lib/ld-linux.so.3 /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# ls /lib/ld*
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3  /lib/ld-linux.so.3
root@linaro-ubuntu-desktop:/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_06/bin# java -version
java version "1.8.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_06-b23)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.6-b23, mixed mode)
```